# CosmosDB Multi-Model read/write on a single database

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

In Build session #BRK3060 Mark Russinovich demos some code that uses both the SQL and Graph APIs on the same database (starts at 45:27):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2zguwKvlQk

Does anyone have any insight into these read/write using multiple APIs on the same database?

Comment: Just now I tried. Created a database in Graph API and able to use SQL Query (select * from c) and Graph Query (g.V()) on same data. It looks useful in Microservice/Distributed Application.